# Show Integer Value in Mysql

Tags: mysql, integer

I have the following table:

```
kingdoms
----------
uuid
name
treasury
challengeswon
```

And I am succesfully listing the values using the following code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `kingdoms` 
WHERE `name`     like '%$search%' 
   OR `treasury` like '%$search%' 
ORDER BY `challengeswon` 
DESC LIMIT 5
```

This is the list I'm getting, and it's ok, but I just need to get rid of those ugly decimals:

> name  treasury    challengesWon
>   Warriors    124164.15625    0
>   Martin  44120.8984375   0
>   Lulita  8797.6513671875 0
>   Noobs   14.210500717163086  0
>   DRAGONES    0   0

How to round the values to integer?  I'm checking a lot of tutorials, but I don't understand where to put the ROUND!

Can you pls. guys help me out?  Thanks!!!!

Comment: . . I dunno.  It would depend on what you want to do.  I would suggest that you delete this question.   Think about your problem and how to communicate it.  And write another question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Whats the structure of `kingdoms` - show some DDL and data please.

Comment: which integer values ?  .. you have *   so ... how we can know the values interesting your ?

Comment: Edited! Any help?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text.  Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for all the corrections, they are edited!  would it be possible to kindly help me with the issue?  Thank in you advance!!!